# Генерация представлений в PowerDesigner для MySQL 5.0

Tags: mysql, sql

Столкнулся с проблемой генерации представления в `Sybase PowerDesigner 15.3.0` для `СУБД MySQL 5.0`. Требуется записать в `crebas.sql` скрипт генерации физической модели данных `PDM` включая таблицы, связи и представления. Всё генерируется без проблем, кроме представлений, `PowerDesigner` словно их не видит. Хотя в настройках, на вкладке `Selection` вьюха помечена.

В чем может быть проблема?